# DrRacket – Finding total number of vowels in list of characters

Tags: string, list, char, racket

I am using DrRacket on the Beginner Language mode.

Code below:

```
(define vowels '(#\a #\e #\i #\o #\u))

(define total 0)

(define (any-in-list lst check)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) (+ 0 total)]
    [(member? (first lst) check) (add1 total)]
    [else (any-in-list (rest lst) check)]))

(define (count-vowels string)
  (any-in-list (string->list string) vowels))

(count-vowels "how do i do this?")
```

The `total` value stays stuck at `1`. After debugging, I realized that the 2nd `cond` statement evaluates to #true and then stops. How can I keep it going for the rest of the list after updating the `total` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to recurse when you found a match.
Also, since `total` is 0, `(+ 0 total)` is always 0, and `(add1 total)` is always 1.

Don't try to use global variables and mutation - recurse and use the recursive value.

```
(cond
    ; The empty list contains nothing, so the result is 0.
    [(empty? lst) 0]
    ; If the first element is a member, the result is
    ; one more than the count in the tail.
    [(member? (first lst) check) (add1 (any-in-list (rest lst) check))]
    ; Otherwise, the count is the same as in the tail.
    [else (any-in-list (rest lst) check)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

molbdnilo's answer explains the OP's issue and provides a correct solution;
since "Beginner Language" is mentioned, it may be worth
looking at how a solution might be constructed using the method
for which BSL (Beginning Student language) in DrRacket is apparently intended.

Following the HtDF ([How to Design Functions](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF)) recipe, one can write the following
***stub***, incorporating ***signature*** and ***purpose***, and "check-expect" ***examples***:
(Note: layout differs slightly from HtDF conventions)

```
(define (count-vowels str)  ;; String -> Natural   ) *stub define* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce the count of vowel characters in str  ) *purpose statement*
  0 )                                              ) *stub body* (a valid result)

(check-expect (count-vowels "")   0 )              ) *examples*
(check-expect (count-vowels "a")  1 )              )
(check-expect (count-vowels "b")  0 )              )
(check-expect (count-vowels "ab") 1 )              )
(check-expect (count-vowels "ae") 2 )              )
```

The first check-expect already passes; now write ***inventory*** and ***template***;
count-vowels will have to do something with each character in the string, but there is no
standard BSL function or template for this. However there is a template for doing something
with the elements of a list:

```
(define (fn lox)  ;; (Listof X) -> Y               ) *template*
  (cond                                            )
    [(empty? lox) ... ]  #|base case|# ;; Y        )
    [else (...           #|something|# ;; X Y -> Y )
            (first lox) (fn (rest lox))) ]))       )

(define vowels (list #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u))         ) *inventory*
(member? x lox)     ;; X (Listof X) -> Bool        )
(string->list str)  ;; String -> (Listof Char)     )
```

So count-vowels can be a composition of `string->list` with a function derived from this
template, for which stub, signature, and check-expects are:

```
(define (count-vowels-in-list loc)  ;; (Listof Char) -> Natural
  0)
(check-expect (count-vowels-in-list          empty)  0 )
(check-expect (count-vowels-in-list (cons #\a '()))  1 )  ;; (+ 1 0)
(check-expect (count-vowels-in-list (cons #\b '()))  0 )  ;; (+ 0 0)
(check-expect (count-vowels-in-list (list #\a #\b))  1 )
(check-expect (count-vowels-in-list (list #\a #\e))  2 )
```

Expanding the template and looking at the first check-expect, the |base case| can be filled in:

```
(define (count-vowels-in-list loc)  ;; (Listof Char) -> Natural
  (cond
    [(empty? loc) 0 ]
    [else (|something| (first loc) (count-vowels-in-list (rest loc))) ]))
```

For the next two check-expects, `(rest loc)` will be '(), so `(|something| #\a 0)` => 1 but
`(|something| #\b 0)` => 0
What distinguishes #\a from #\b is that `(member? #\a vowels)` => #true but
`(member? #\b vowels)` => #false so a descriptive name for |something| is add-1-if-vowel:

```
(define (add-1-if-vowel chr n)  ;; Char Natural -> Natural
  (if (member? chr vowels)
      (add1 n)
      n))
```

So a complete solution developed by following this systematic design method is:

```
(define vowels (list #\a #\e #\i #\o #\u))

(define (add-1-if-vowel chr n)      ;; Char Natural -> Natural
  (if (member? chr vowels)
      (add1 n)
      n))

(define (count-vowels-in-list loc)  ;; (Listof Char) -> Natural
  (cond
    [(empty? loc) 0 ]
    [else (add-1-if-vowel (first loc) (count-vowels-in-list (rest loc))) ]))

(define (count-vowels str)          ;; String -> Natural
  (count-vowels-in-list (string->list str)))

(check-expect (count-vowels "")   0 )
(check-expect (count-vowels "a")  1 )
(check-expect (count-vowels "b")  0 )
(check-expect (count-vowels "ab") 1 )
(check-expect (count-vowels "ae") 2 )
(check-expect (count-vowels "how do i do this?") 5 )  ;; ^ (this is how :) ^
```