# How do you split a list in scheme into n evenly sized chunks?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying out some practice problems at in racket and am stuck at this one

What I want to do is define a list such as (partition '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3) and then call  return '((1 2) (3 4) (3 4)). (three evenly sized partition)

For Example (partition '(1 2 3 4) 3) would provide the output
(((1) (2) (3 4))
Here 3 which is n is number of partitions to be made

Below I have tried my hands at the problem

```
(define (threesize n xs)
  (let loop ([grouped '()] [xs xs] [l (length xs])
    (cond
      [(empty? xs)
       (reverse grouped)]
      [(<= l n)
       (loop (cons xs grouped) '() 0)]
      [else (let-values ([(taken dropped) (split-at xs n)])
              (loop (cons taken grouped)
                    dropped
                    (- l n)))])))
```

Very new to programming and racket in general, so excuse my skills on that matter. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For those "new to programming and racket" it may be interesting to look at how a problem
like this can be addressed using the
HtDF ([How to Design Functions](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF))
design method with a BSL (Beginning Student language) in DrRacket.

Start with a ***stub***, incorporating ***signature*** and ***purpose***, and a ***minimal*** "check-expect" ***example***:
(Note: layout differs slightly from HtDF conventions)

```
(define (partition xs n) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof (Listof X)) ; *stub define* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks                             ; *purpose statement*
  (list (list)))                                                  ; *stub body* (a valid result)

(check-expect (partition '() 1)  '( () ))                         ; *example*
```

This can be run in DrRacket:

```
Language: Beginning Student with List Abbreviations
The test passed!
>
```

The next steps in HtDF are ***template*** and ***inventory***. There is a generic template
for functions with a list argument, and because it can be seen that the function will have
to "take" list elements, functions likely to be useful can be listed in inventory

```
(define (fn lox) ;; (Listof X) -> Y                  ; *template*
  (cond                                              ;
    [(empty? lox) ... ]  #|base case|# ;; Y          ;
    [else (...           #|something|# ;; X Y -> Y   ;
            (first lox) (fn (rest lox))) ]))         ;
            
(take xs n-to-take) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof X)  ; *inventory* 
(drop xs n-to-drop) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof X)  ;

#| (take and drop are not in BSL, so define them now) |#
(define (take xs n) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof X)
  ;; produce initial n elements of xs
  (if (zero? n)
      '()
      (cons (car xs) (take (cdr xs) (- n 1)))))
      
(define (drop xs n) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof X)
  ;; produce rest of xs after n elements
  (if (zero? n)
      xs
      (drop (cdr xs) (- n 1))))
```

Partitioning will consist of repeatedly taking and dropping a number of elements, the number
generally being `(quotient (length xs) n)`, so introduce this parameter now:

```
(define (partition xs n) ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof (Listof X))
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks of length (quotient (length xs) n) (when possible)
  (partition-at xs n (quotient (length xs) n)))

(define (partition-at xs n len) ;; (Listof X) Nat Nat -> (Listof (Listof X))
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks of length len   (stub adapted from template)
  (cond
    [(= n 1) (list xs) ]
    [else    (error "not yet defined") ]))

(check-expect (partition    '(1 2) 1)   '( (1 2) ))
(check-expect (partition-at '(a b) 1 2) '( (a b) ))
```

Looking at the next `check-expects` (below) and the **template**, one can see how to complete
`partition-at` (the generic template is for processing list elements one at a time, so here `first` becomes `take` and `rest` becomes `drop`):

```
(check-expect (partition-at '(a b) 2 1) '( (a) (b) ))
(check-expect (partition-at '(a b c d) 2 2) '( (a b) (c d) ))

(define (partition-at xs n len) ;; (Listof X) Nat Nat -> (Listof (Listof X))
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks of length len (plus excess)
  (cond
    [(= n 1) (list xs) ]
    [else    (cons (take xs len)
                   (partition-at (drop xs len) (- n 1) len)) ]))
```

So the complete solution (given take and drop), with some more tests, is:

```
(define (partition xs n)  ;; (Listof X) Nat -> (Listof (Listof X))
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks
  (partition-at xs n (quotient (length xs) n)))

(define (partition-at xs n len)  ;; (Listof X) Nat Nat -> (Listof (Listof X))
  ;; produce xs divided into n chunks of length len
  (cond
    [(= n 1) (list xs) ]
    [else    (cons (take xs len)
                   (partition-at (drop xs len) (- n 1) len)) ]))

(check-expect (partition '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3) '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
(check-expect (partition '(1 2 3 4) 3) '((1) (2) (3 4)))
(check-expect (partition '(1 2 3 4) 5) '(() () () () (1 2 3 4)))
```

(Of course, this is not the most efficient solution, but it didn't seem to require any big
leaps of intuition, and once the HtDF [systematic program design method](https://www.edx.org/course/how-to-code-simple-data?index=product&queryID=6227a558c5e777209fd4009f04b970d0&position=1)
has been learnt, simple functions can often be written down "correct by construction" :)

Comment: Another example of this systematic function construction technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71063476/16981884)

Answer (score 1):

I have written this code for you.  The idea is, you go once over the list to detect the size of each group (namely `count`) and a second time to create the groups.

```
(define partition
  (lambda (data num/groups)
    (let loop ((l data)
               (len 0)
               (ret (lambda (group rest __ ___)
                      (if (null? group)
                          rest
                          (cons group rest)))))
      (if (null? l)
        (ret '() '() 1 (integer-ceiling len num/groups))
        (loop
          (cdr l)
          (+ 1 len)
          (lambda (g r i count)
            (let ((g (cons (car l) g)))
              (if (= i count)
                (ret '() (cons g r) 1 count)
                (ret g r (+ 1 i) count)))))))))
(partition '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3)
```

Comment: integer-ceiling: unbound identifier in: integer-ceiling
this error is popping up @alinsoar

Comment: @WaitimuKimani Sorry, I forgot to tell that I was working with mit/scheme.  I do not know the `integer-ceiling` for your system.  The idea is, (integer-ceiling 10) = 10, (integer-ceiling 10.01) = 11.

Comment: I am working on Racket so this wont run for me. Please let me know if you have any alternatives. Thank you.

Comment: @WaitimuKimani you need to look for a standard ceiling function.  You can write your own. Sorry, I cannot help more.