# DrRacket Using accumulator as List-ref index

Tags: list, for-loop, indexing, racket, accumulator

I am trying to write a function that take a list and iterates over each element in the list if the number is even I want that number to be added to the previous number in the list.

I was thinking an accumulator will count up from 0 with each iteration giving a position for each element in the list.

If the number in the list is even I want to add that number to the previous number in the list.
Hence why I am trying to use the accumulator as an index for list-ref. I don't know how to write it to get the accumulator  value  for the previous iteration (+ i (list-ref a-list(- acc 1)))?

```
(define loopl (lambda (l)
                (for/fold
                 ([acc 0])([i l])
                  (cond
                    [(even? i)(+ i (list-ref  (- acc 1) l))]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t9Qg.png)

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a function which, when given the list `'(1 2 3 4 5)` returns the list `'(1 3 3 7 5)` or do you want it to return `'(3 2 7 4 5)` instead?

Comment: What will happen if the first element of the list is even?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not quite clear about the value to be returned by this function:
this answer assumes that it is a total of even elements together with their previous elements.
The function is developed using the
HtDF ([How to Design Functions](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF))
design method with a BSL (Beginning Student language) in DrRacket.

Start with a ***stub***, incorporating ***signature*** and ***purpose***, and a ***minimal*** "check-expect" ***example***:
(Note: layout differs slightly from HtDF conventions)

```
(define (sum-evens-with-prev xs) ;; (Listof Integer) -> Integer ; *stub define* ;; *signature*
  ;; produce total of each even x with its previous element     ; *purpose statement*
  0)                                                            ; *stub body* (a valid result)

(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '()) 0)                      ; *minimal example*
```

This can be run in DrRacket:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student with List Abbreviations
The test passed!
>
```

The next steps in HtDF are ***template*** and ***inventory***. For a function with one list
argument the "natural recursion" list template is likely to be appropriate;

```
(define (fn xs) ;; (Listof X) -> Y                 ; *template*
  (cond                                            ;
    [(empty? xs) ... ]  #|base case|# ;; Y         ;
    [else (...          #|something|# ;; X Y -> Y  ;
            (first xs) (fn (rest xs))) ]))         ;
```

With this template the function and the next tests become:

```
(define (sum-evens-with-prev xs) ;; (Listof Number) -> Number
  ;; produce total of each even x with its previous element (prev of first is 0)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) 0 ]                  #|base case: from minimal example|#
    [else (error "with arguments: "   #|something: ?|#
            (first xs) (sum-evens-with-prev (rest xs))) ]))

(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1)) 0)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(2)) 2)
```

These tests fail, but the error messages and purpose statement suggest what is required:
the `(... #|something|#` from the template has to choose whether to add `(first xs)`:

```
(define (sum-evens-with-prev xs) ;; (Listof Integer) -> Integer
  ;; produce total of each even x with its previous element (prev of first is 0)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) 0 ]
    [else
     (if (even? (first xs))
        (+ (first xs) (sum-evens-with-prev (rest xs)))
        (sum-evens-with-prev (rest xs))) ]))
```

Now all 3 tests pass! Time for more `check-expects` (note: careful introduction of
check-expects is a way of clarifying ones understanding of the requirements, and
points one to the code to be added):

```
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1 1)) 0)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1 2)) 3)
```

> Ran 5 tests.
> 1 of the 5 tests failed.
>
> Check failures:
> Actual value 2 differs from 3, the expected value.

`sum-evens-with-prev` needs the `prev` value to include in the even? case:
make it available by introducing it as an argument (renaming the function), add
the appropriate arguments to the recursive calls, the function now just calls
`sum-evens-and-prev`:

```
(define (sum-evens-and-prev xs prev) ;; (Listof Integer) Integer -> Integer
  ;; produce total of each even x and prev
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) 0 ]
    [else
     (if (even? (first xs))
         (+ prev (first xs) (sum-evens-and-prev (rest xs) (first xs)))
         (sum-evens-and-prev (rest xs) (first xs))) ]))

(define (sum-evens-with-prev xs) ;; (Listof Integer) -> Integer
  ;; produce total of each even x with its previous element (prev of first is 0)
  (sum-evens-and-prev xs 0))
```

(just add some more tests, and all is well :)

```
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(0 2)) 2)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(2 1)) 2)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1 3)) 0)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(2 2)) 6)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1 2 3 4)) 10)
(check-expect (sum-evens-with-prev '(1 2 3 3 5 6 6)) 26)

Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Beginning Student with List Abbreviations.
All 11 tests passed!
>
```

Comment: [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176953/16981884) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71063476/16981884) of this [systematic function development](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF) technique.

Answer (score 1):

The `(for/fold)` form requires a `(values)` clause, and it is in that which you would put the conditional form.

Assuming you want only the new list as the return value, you would also want a `#:result` clause following the iteration variables.

```
(define loopl
  (lambda (l)
    (for/fold
     ([index 0]
      [acc '()]
      #:result acc)
     ([i l])
      (values [+ index 1]
              [append acc
                      (if (and (> index 0)
                               (even? i))
                          (list (+ i (list-ref l (- index 1))))
                          (list i))]))))
```

This should give the correct answer.

Comment: I tried running it but it comes up with a syntax error :(
So the index keeps track of each position in the list that i iterates over, and the products of which are appended to the empty list (acc)?
what does #:result do? i have never seen that before

Comment: `#:result` is a keyword modifier specific to `(for/fold)` and related Racket library forms. It indicates a specific return value, in this case the accumulated list.

Comment: BTW, what syntax error is it indicating? I was able to run it with no problem, so I don't know why it is coming out differently for you. Also, which Language Pack do you have it set to? I ran the code as `#lang racket`, but it may not behave the same under some of the other language settings.

Comment: By default, without a `#:result` clause, `(for/fold)` returns a multivalue consisting of the final values of *all* the iteration variables. See the [DrRacket documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29) for more details on this.

Comment: yeah i'm using #lang racket;
it says:
 
for/fold: bad syntax in: (for/fold ((index 0) (acc (quote ())) #:result acc) ((i l)) (values (+ index 1) (append acc (if (and (> index 0) (even? i)) (list (+ i (list-ref l (- index 1)))) (list i)))))

Comment: Could you try removing the `#:result` clause? It won't give quite the right return value, but it should be possible to work around that. Also, which version of DrRacket are you using? I am running v8.3 here.

Comment: If I wanted to add another condition into the current expression that if the iterator is over an odd number  multiply it by 3 how can I do it? 
````
(if (odd? i) (* i 3))
````

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to repeatedly call `list-ref` in a loop: that makes for horrible performance.  Remember that `(list-ref l i)` takes time proportional to `i`: in your case you're going to be calling `list-ref` with the index being, potentially 0, 1, ..., and that going to result in quadratic performance, which is bad.

Instead there's a neat trick if you want to iterate over elements of a list offset by a fixed amount (here 1): iterate over two lists: the list itself *and its tail*.

In addition you need to check that the first element of the list is not even (because there is no previous element in that case, so this is an error).

Finally I'm not entirely sure what you wanted to return from the function: I'm assuming it's the sum.

```
(define (accum-even-previouses l)
  (unless (not (even? (first l)))
    ;; if the first elt is even this is an error
    (error 'accum-even-previouses "even first elt"))
  (for/fold ([accum 0])
            ([this (in-list (rest l))]
             [previous (in-list l)])
    (+ accum (if (even? this)
                 (+ this previous)
                 0))))
```